# pgRouting one way segment direction

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2pgrouting

How can one acquire information about direction of a one way road from OpenStreetMap data converted to a postresql database with osm2pgrouting?

Answer (score 2):

The `cost` and `reverse_cost` attributes of the `ways` table give you this information. The direction itself depends on the geometry.